# Least Squares Fitting - Logarithmic

Tags: math-software, regression

Is there any software that will fit a set of 2D points using a logarithmic curve?

I found [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingLogarithmic.html), which looks like the formulas I need, but I don't think I have a fancy enough calculator to solve that for me.

WolframAlpha has a LeastSquares[] function, but it looks like it only does linear regressions.

Comment: Is this an example of what you're trying to do: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log+fit+%7B15.2%2C8.9%7D%2C%7B31.1%2C9.9%7D%2C%7B38.6%2C10.3%7D%2C%7B52.2%2C10.7%7D%2C%7B75.4%2C11.4%7D ?

Comment: Any spreadsheet that does linear fits would allow you to take the log of your data before fitting.

Comment: @unit3000-21: That looks exactly like what I was looking for. Didn't know the syntax. Is there a reference somewhere? Anyway, if you made that an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%20fit%20%7B15.2,8.9%7D,%7B31.1,9.9%7D,%7B38.6,10.3%7D,%7B52.2,10.7%7D,%7B75.4,11.4%7D)'s an example of what you're trying to do in Wolfram Alpha.  I think you can do the same thing in Mathematica using similar, or identical notation.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be surprised if Wolfram Alpha is actually doing what Ross suggested: transform the $x$ data by $t_j = \log(x_j)$.  Then $y = a \log(b x)$ becomes $y = a t + c$ where $t = \log(x)$ and $c = a \log(b)$.  Thus this becomes a *linear* least-squares problem.

Comment: That's a pretty clever way of solving it.

Comment: But not necessarily the best method, as the transformation with logarithms will also distort the errors inherent in the data. Most software (yes, even Excel!) allows for nonlinear least-squares fitting; look at their documentation for details.

Comment: What I would suggest is to use the log transformation to get initial values for the parameters and then use a nonlinear fitter with those as the initial values. My experience with nonlinear fitting is that having good initial parameter values is essential.

Comment: @marty, that is in fact the proper approach for these things. Use the linearization to obtain good initial values for your NLLS method.

Comment: For a standard least-squares in the $y$ direction with the $x$ values considered as exact (which is what is happening here), transforming the $x$ values doesn't cause any "distortion".  It really is a linear problem.  If you were doing "total least-squares" where errors in both $x$ and $y$ are allowed, you would be right, the problem for a logarithmic fit would be nonlinear.