# Linearizing Logarithmic Function

Tags: linearization

I have a given set of data points (y,x) with uncertainties.

When I plot those points on a graph, the trendline appears to follow the equation y = c + a*ln(x).

I want to be able to find the uncertainty in "a".

So just like linearizing an exponential function $y=e^{ax}$ as $\text{ln}(y) = ax$, and we can get the uncertainty in "a" by graphing the minimum and maximum slopes and averaging it out,

Is there a way to linearize a logarithmic function $y=a \text{ln}(x)$ ?

Thank you.

EDIT: Link to duplicate answer in comments.

Comment: Not sure what you might mean by "linearize".  What's wrong with $e^{y/a}=x$?

Comment: I have a given set of y and x which has a logarithmic relationship, and I need to find "a".

Comment: Ok, why not take $a=\frac y{\ln x}$ then?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear; I have a given set of data points (x, y) with uncertainties, and when I plot them on a y vs x graph and draw a trendline through it, I get an equation that is like y=c+a*ln(x). I want to be able to find the uncertainty in "a".

Comment: Please edit your post to ask a clear and coherent question.

Comment: Yes, should have done that earlier

Comment: Found the answer while digging: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181844/least-squares-fitting-logarithmic See Robert Israel's Answer

Answer (score 1):

$$y = a \ln x \implies e^{y/a} = x $$

Comment: How would I go about finding a if I have a given set of y and x?